# TableView does not show data

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

I am trying to fill my `UITableView` with some data I receive from a GET request. I don't know why but if in my `numberOfRowsInSection`, I return an specific value (for example, 8) it represents the info. If y return the value of my array filled by the request, the `UITableView` does not add any row:

```
class DashboardTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var userData = [String]()
    var secondUserData = [String]()
    var name: String = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }

    /* This function gets the user account information from a JSON in a simple request */
    private func loadUserData(completion: @escaping (_ myArray: [String]) -> Void) {
        let session = Twitter.sharedInstance().sessionStore.session()
        let client = TWTRAPIClient.withCurrentUser()
        let userInfoURL = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json"
        let params = ["user_id": session?.userID]
        var clientError : NSError?
        let request = client.urlRequest(withMethod: "GET", url: userInfoURL, parameters: params, error: &clientError)

        client.sendTwitterRequest(request) { (response, data, connectionError) -> Void in
            if connectionError != nil {
                print("Error: \(connectionError)")
            }

            do {
                let json = JSON(data: data!)
                if  let userName = json["name"].string,
                    let description = json["description"].string,
                    let followersCount = json["followers_count"].int,
                    let favouritesCount = json["favourites_count"].int,
                    let followingCount = json["friends_count"].int,
                    let lang = json["lang"].string,
                    let nickname = json["screen_name"].string {
                        self.userData.append(userName)
                        self.userData.append(nickname)
                        self.userData.append(String(followersCount))
                        self.userData.append(String(followingCount))
                        self.userData.append(String("22"))
                        self.userData.append(lang)
                        self.userData.append(description)
                        self.userData.append("No country")

                        completion(self.userData)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /* This closure helps us to fill the labels once the request has been finished in loadUserData */
    func manageUserData(label: UILabel, index: Int) {
        loadUserData {
            (result: [String]) in
            label.text = result[index]
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return self.userData.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let rowNumber = indexPath.row
        let cellIdentifier = "TableViewCell"
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? TableViewCellController else {
            fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of TableViewCellController.")
        }

        switch rowNumber {
        case 0:
            cell.titlePlaceholder.text = "Name:"
            manageUserData(label: cell.valuePlaceholder, index: rowNumber)
        case 1:
            cell.titlePlaceholder.text = "Nickname:"
            manageUserData(label: cell.valuePlaceholder, index: rowNumber)
        case 2:
            cell.titlePlaceholder.text = "Followers:"
            manageUserData(label: cell.valuePlaceholder, index: rowNumber)
        case 3:
            cell.titlePlaceholder.text = "Following:"
            manageUserData(label: cell.valuePlaceholder, index: rowNumber)
        case 4:
            cell.titlePlaceholder.text = "Tweets:"
            manageUserData(label: cell.valuePlaceholder, index: rowNumber)
        case 5:
            cell.titlePlaceholder.text = "Language:"
            manageUserData(label: cell.valuePlaceholder, index: rowNumber)
        case 6:
            cell.titlePlaceholder.text = "Biography:"
            manageUserData(label: cell.valuePlaceholder, index: rowNumber)
        case 7:
            cell.titlePlaceholder.text = "Country:"
            manageUserData(label: cell.valuePlaceholder, index: rowNumber)
        default:
            cell.titlePlaceholder.text = "?"
            cell.valuePlaceholder.text = "?"
        }

        return cell
    }
}
```

Any idea why this is happening ?
Thank you very much!!

**UPDATE!**

I solved this problem adding self.tableView.reloadData() after completion() inside loadUserData() function. Hope it helps!

Comment: Add a breakpoint at the beginning of `override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {`
 to check if this method is called

Comment: it is about your request. Try printing your json right after `let json = JSON(data: data!)` and see what's coming up

Comment: It does both things only in case I return an specific value in override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int

Comment: Try `tableView.reloadData()` after you complete downloading data from API

Comment: Already tried to use self.tableView.realoadData() and it still does not load it if I return de count of my array at numberOfRowsInSection function

Comment: Are you downloading data from the API multiple times ?

Comment: I would download data when viewDidLoad, append it to the array and refresh the tableView

Comment: Just tried it, that was the problem. Thank you very much mate!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift solution:

```
tableView.reloadData()
```

If you are calling it not from the main thread:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Already tried to use self.tableView.realoadData() and it still does not load it if I return de count of my array at numberOfRowsInSection function

Comment: Where in the code are you reloading the tableView ?

Comment: I've tried to do it right after completion in the method where I do the request

Comment: Then you have to use the code in my answer with DispatchQueue.main.async

Comment: It still does not work. It's really strange. Can't understand why it charges data only if I return an specific number in numberOfRowsInSection function

Comment: This would be a much better answer if you mentioned that needs to be called from inside (and at the end of) the completion handler.

Answer (score 0):

You must reload table view data after receiving request with

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: Already tried to use self.tableView.realoadData() and it still does not load it if I return de count of my array at numberOfRowsInSection function